# Troubleshooting "program does not contain a static 'Main' method" when it clearly does...?

Tags: c#, compilation

My MS Visual C# program was compiling and running just fine.
I close MS Visual C# to go off and do other things in life.

I reopen it and (before doing anything else) go to "Publish" my program and get the following error message:

> Program C:\myprogram.exe does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Huh?  Yes it does... and it was all working 15 min earlier.  Sure, I can believe that I accidentally hit something or done something before I closed it up... but what?  How do I troubleshoot this?

My Program.cs file looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace SimpleAIMLEditor
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            Application.Run(new mainSAEForm());
        }
    }
}
```

...and there are some comments in there.    There are no other errors.

Help?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Are the properties on the file set to Compile?

Comment: That was it... I was looking at "build Actions" before I closed it and must have accidentally key-stroked my way to set the Program.cs to not compile.  Thanks!

Comment: How can I check this? I'm having the same problem here... PS: Using vs2012

Comment: Select the file in the project tree and open the properties window. The top value should be right one.

Answer (score 62):

I was struggle with this error just because **one of my `class library` projects** `was set acceddentaly` to be an **console application**

so make sure your class library projects is class library in Output type

[image]

Comment: In dotnet core, this adds the following to my project.csproj:
`<PropertyGroup>
    ....
    <ApplicationIcon />
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <StartupObject />
</PropertyGroup>
`

Answer (score 24):

Oke, I was looking at this issue as well. And in my case the solutions was too easy.
I added a new empty project to the solution. The newly added project is automatically set as a console application. But since the project added was a 'empty' project, no Program.cs existed in that new project. (As expected)

All I needed to do was change the output type of the project properties to Class library

Answer (score 17):

If you have a WPF or Silverlight application, make sure that App.xaml has "ApplicationDefinition" as the BuildAction on the File Properties.

Answer (score 11):

I had changed

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
```

to

```
public async static void Main(string[] args)
```

The problem is that it needs to be a task:

```
public async static Task Main(string[] args)
```

Answer (score 10):

I had this error and solved by this solution.

```
--> Right click on the project

--> and select "Properties"

--> then set "Output Type" to "Class Library".
```

Comment: I have no clue how this setting got changed on a 10 year old project, but this was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Check your project's properties. On the "Application" tab, select your `Program` class as the Startup object:

[image]

Comment: That only needs to be set when there are two static Main methods.

Comment: What if that dropdown menu is empty?

Comment: Accidentally changed my class properties and it deleted that property, even after re-typing how it was.. Fixed my issue thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

That's odd. Does your program compile and run successfully and only fail on 'Publish' or does it fail on every compile now?

Also, have you perhaps changed the file's properties' `Build Action` to something other than `Compile`?

Comment: Yes - it was failing on every compile and yes - I did accidentally change my build action on Program.cs to "none"  :)

Comment: How can a 20k+ rep user post a "comment" as answer, and still get upvotes? Or does this actually somehow answer the question and I just didn't notice it?

Comment: Nevermind, this is 2008 (I thought it was recent because it was in LQ queue, my bad).

Comment: @Alisson firstly, yes, the answer was from 2008, but the second paragraph also answered the question.

Comment: @configurator yep, my bad, I just didn't notice. I think you should have edited your answer to look more like an actual answer, and it should be the accepted one (since you were the first to post). But these things happen, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and its because I wasnt using the latest version of C# (C# 7.3 as of writing this) and I had to change the below `internal` access modifier to `public`.

```
internal class Program
 {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //My Code
    }
  }
```

or ammend the `.csproj` to use the latest version of C# (this way meant I could still keep the above class as `internal`):

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
    <NoWin32Manifest>true</NoWin32Manifest>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

For me same error occurred because I renamed the **namespace** of the Program class. 

The **"Startup object"** field in **"Application" tab** of the project still referenced the old namespace. Selecting new startup object solved the problem and also removed the obsolete entry from that list.

You may also want to update **"Default namespace"** field in the same "Application" tab.

Answer (score 1):

My problem is that I accidentally set the arguments for Main

static void Main(**object value**)

thanks to my refactoring tool. Took couple mins to figure out but should help someone along the way.

Answer (score 1):

It is important that the `Main` method is placed in the class that is properly configured in Visual Studio as a start-up object:

- Right-click your project in project explorer; choose "Properties..."
- In the properties dialog, choose "Application" tab
- In the application tab, choose `SimpleAIMLEditor.Program` from the drop-down for your start-up object

Now run your application again. The error will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me: Close MS Visual Studio, then start Visual Studio and open the solution. The error message was then gone.

Answer (score 0):

What I found is that the Program.cs file was not part of the solution. 
I did an add existing item and added the file (Program.cs) back to the solution.

This corrected the error:
Error   1   Program '..... does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Answer (score 0):

In my case (where none of the proposed solutions fit), the problem was I used `async/await` where the signature for `main` method looked this way:

```
static async void Main(string[] args)
```

I simply removed `async` so the `main` method looked this way:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

I also removed all instances of `await` and used `.Result` for async calls, so my console application could compile happily.

Comment: the `async Task` was also the problem for me - because I was targeting the wrong version of C#. I added this to my csproj and it all started working: `<LangVersion>7.1</LangVersion><TargetLatestRuntimePatch>true</TargetLatestRuntimePatch>`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was an XUnit test library showing this error. I had mistakenly deleted the `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` package.

Answer (score 0):

In my dotnet core 3.1 project I had created a new class/file instead of Program.cs that contained the Main method.

I had to update the Startup object to my new class name in Project Properties

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but what solved it for me was making sure my launch.json and .csproj file were pointing to the same framework.

In launch.json this

```
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/net6.0-windows/myproject.dll"
```

Was not the same as this in .csproj

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had this error in some of my tests projects (Application.Tests, Domain.Tests, WebApp.Tests) simply because the versions of nugget packages for '**Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk**' installed in these projects were different.
So what i did was to make the **versions** of the nugget packages for "*Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk*" **are the same**.

Answer (score 0):

Main should be spelled with an uppercase M.
I had mine in lower case, c++ style.

Comment: While this is true, for applications that are not using top-level statements or for versions of c# earlier than 9, this question was already marked answered for a completely different reason.