# CS5001 Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Tags: c#

I have looked around other forums and can't find the answer anywhere. Can anyone help me?

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    csProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").FirstOrDefault();
    if (csProcess == null) { return; } // notepad isn't running
    modules = csProcess.Modules;
    foreach(ProcessModule module in modules) {
        if (module.ModuleName == "client.dll") {
            int ClientDLL = Mem.Module("client.dll");
        }

        int LocalPlayer = ReadProcessMemory(ClientDLL + m_dwLocalPlayer);
        int LocalTeam = ReadProcessMemory(LocalPlayer + m_iTeamNum);
        int CrossHairID = ReadProcessMemory(LocalPlayer + m_iCrossHairID);
        int EmemyinCrossHair = ReadProcessMemory(ClientDLL + m_dwEntityList +
            ((CrossHairID - 1) * EntLoopDist));
        int EnemyTeam = ReadProcessMemory(EnemyInCrossHair + m_iTeamNum);
        int EnemyHealth = ReadProcessMemory(EnemyinCrossHair + m_iHealth);

        if (EnemyHealth > 0 && EnemyTeam != LocalTeam) {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, Control.MousePosition.X,
                Control.MousePosition.Y, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, Control.MousePosition.X,
                Control.MousePosition.Y, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

I need step by step instructions please.

Comment: Check `Build Action` & `Output Type` on project properties, then check availability of `App.xaml` file. Which one you want to build: a WinForms app, console app or class library?

Comment: I want to export as dll so... console?

Comment: Try using class library option as output type in Project => Properties menu (note that by default it may build as console app). Console app requires `STAThreadAttribute` to run with `Main` method (see similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607702/does-not-contain-a-static-main-method-suitable-for-an-entry-point).

Answer (score 1):

What you want to get? Dll-library, or standalone application (.exe-file, console app e.g.)?
If you want to get exe-application, try to add `public` modifier for Main method - `public static void Main(string[] args)`
For dll-library:
1. Create New Project, "Class Library" type.
2. You already have a file Class1.cs. Replace the text in the Class1.cs:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public static class Class1
    {
        static void MyMethod()
        {
            csProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").FirstOrDefault();
            //Your another code
        }
    }
}
```

3. Build project and use ClassLibrary1.dll from bin->Debug or bin-Release folder by adding this dll as Reference in Console/WinForm/Wpf applications.
4. Use your dll-class like this - `ClassLibrary1.Class1.MyMethod();`

Comment: I did this, and everything is now surrounded in error messages./