# Visual Studio Code: "Program has more than one entry point defined"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, csproj

I created a [C# project using **Visual Studio Code**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio-code). This project contains two .cs files, *Addition.cs* and *Substraction.cs*. Both files contain a *main()* function and both files contain two different programs.

Code in the *Addition.cs* file:

```
using System;

namespace Example
{
    class Addition
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int sum = 3 + 2;
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Code in the *Substraction.cs* file

```
using System;

namespace Example
{
    class Substraction
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int sub = 3 - 2;
            Console.WriteLine(sub);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to test both the programs one by one, but when I do

> "dotnet run"

It fails with the above error.

I know because of two main() functions (entry points) in the same project is creating this error, but this can be overcome in Visual Studio by setting up a startup project.

I am using **Visual Studio Code**, where I am unable to set up a startup project.

Is there a way to set up an entry point for a C# project in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If both entry points are in the same project, setting the startup project wouldn't do anything anyway. You need to set the startup *object*.

This can be done in the project properties dialog in a full version of Visual Studio (look for "Startup object" under Application), or in the .csproj file by setting `Project/PropertyGroup/StartupObject`:

```
<StartupObject>Example.Addition</StartupObject>
```

Alternatively consider using a single `Main()` entry point which takes a command-line argument.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio Code then add the following line.

```
<StartupObject>ExampleNameSpace.ExampleClass</StartupObject>
```

For **ExampleNameSpace**, type your namespace name

For **ExampleClass**, type your class name.

Let if I consider that your Namespace is CSharp and the class in which you defined the Main method is MainClass then your .csproj should look like this.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <StartupObject>CSharp.MainClass</StartupObject>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Note: This code sample is for .Net5

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for your answer but it looks like your answer is conveying same thing what @Ic. is provided in his/her answer

Comment: Yes, it is. But he hasn't mentioned where to put this code when you are using Visual Studio Code in the .csproj file. I have written this for absolute beginners.