# Building two programs in a C# project

Tags: c#, .net-core, csproj

**Short Version**

In a C# project created by `dotnet new console`, all of the `*.cs` files, even the ones in subdirectories, are compiled into a single program. If there are two classes with `Main` functions, it fails to build. How do I tell it to build two programs?

**More Details**

As a newcomer to C# and all of the related tools, I followed the tutorials, and learned how to create a minimal project by running `dotnet new console`, throw in some `*.cs` files, and run the resulting program with `dotnet run`. I even made a usable "release" with `dotnet publish`. All of this is coordinated by this `*.csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

If `A.cs` and `B.cs` both declare `Main`, the build fails with `error CS0017: Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.`. So I have a clue that there is a `/main` option, but I don't know where to put it. `dotnet run /main A.cs` is not it.

The goal is to have something that looks like `dotnet run /main A.cs`, but actually works; and to have `dotnet publish` create both `A.exe` and `B.exe` (or the closest equivalent for the target platform).

I expect that I will have to do some non-trivial `*.csproj` editing, but all I know about that file is that `dotnet new` created it, and `dotnet add package` put in the PackageReference. The actual build rules are hidden away in the `Sdk` and I don't know how to control what it does.

**Related question**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152454/visual-studio-code-program-has-more-than-one-entry-point-defined) looks the same as mine, but the accepted answer only builds one of the programs.

Comment: You pass arguments into the Main method, why not have branching logic there?

Comment: one project -> one executable. This is why there are _solutions_: a solution can contain more than one project, and therefore produce more than one executable

Comment: That's a surprising definition of the word "project" for me. "Project" sounds like a big enough thing to encompass a lot more than 2 programs. "Solutions" I have heard of but never knew what they were about. I guess now is the time to read up on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have two separate projects to produce two separate EXE files. Shared code will usually go in a third "Library" project that both depend on. Though you can make one application project depend on the other, but this would be a bit odd.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to reference another project. You can use `dotnet add reference` command or this command `dotnet add [<PROJECT>] reference [-f|--framework] <PROJECT_REFERENCES>`.

Just replace PROJECT with your project name and PROJECT_REFERENCES with the project you want to reference or you can directly type project references.

```
    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="app.csproj" />
      <ProjectReference Include="..\lib2\lib2.csproj" />
      <ProjectReference Include="..\lib1\lib1.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

in the project file.

This will build you all projects with the referenced project also.