# Getting "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point" when building using docker, why?

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

I'm running into an issue using Docker and couldn't find a proper solution.

I'm trying to build a Docker image using .NET SDK 2.1.

The thing is that when Docker tries to run the build statement, it fails and the error output is

> CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method
> suitable for an entry point

The funny thing is that if I perform the build statement on command line locally, it works fine.

I have already checked my LanguageVersion tag on the project and it is 7.3.

Here is my Docker file

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS builder  
WORKDIR /src
COPY ./nuget  ./nuget
COPY ./NuGet.Config ./
COPY Services/AadTracking ./

# Copy all the referenced projects

COPY ./Services/AadTracking/Company/Company.Service.AadTracking/Company.Service.AadTracking.csproj ./AadTracking/Company/Company.Service.AadTracking/Company.Service.AadTracking.csproj
COPY ./Services/AadTracking/Office.Re.Service.AadTracking/Office.Re.Service.AadTracking.csproj ./AadTracking/Office.Re.Service.AadTracking/Office.Re.Service.AadTracking.csproj
COPY ./Services/AadTracking/Company/Office.Re.Service.AadTracking.Company/Office.Re.Service.AadTracking.Company.csproj ./AadTracking/Company/Office.Re.Service.AadTracking.Company/Office.Re.Service.AadTracking.Company.csproj
COPY ./Services/AadTracking/Office.Re.Service.AadTracking.EventStore/Office.Re.Service.AadTracking.EventStore.csproj ./AadTracking/Office.Re.Service.AadTracking.EventStore/Office.Re.Service.AadTracking.EventStore.csproj

# Restore packages
RUN dotnet restore "./AadTracking/Company/Company.Service.AadTracking/Company.Service.AadTracking.csproj"

RUN dotnet build -c Debug --no-restore "./AadTracking/Company/Company.Service.AadTracking/Company.Service.AadTracking.csproj"

# COPY source code 
#aad tracking
COPY ./Services/AadTracking/Company/Company.Service.AadTracking ./AadTracking/Company/Company.Service.AadTracking/
COPY ./Services/AadTracking/Office.Re.Service.AadTracking ./AadTracking/Office.Re.Service.AadTracking/
COPY ./Services/AadTracking/Company/Office.Re.Service.AadTracking.Company ./AadTracking/Company/Office.Re.Service.AadTracking.Company/
COPY ./Services/AadTracking/Office.Re.Service.AadTracking.EventStore ./AadTracking/Office.Re.Service.AadTracking.EventStore/

# Publish
RUN dotnet publish "./AadTracking/Company/Company.Service.AadTracking/Company.Service.AadTracking.csproj" -c Debug -o "../../dist"

# #Build the app image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime  
WORKDIR /app  

ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Switch
ENV REINSURANCE_INSTANCE Docker-dev 

COPY --from=builder /dist .  

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Company.Service.AadTracking.dll"]
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 106):

I know this is little bit late to answer. Still VS 2019 has the same issue with .NET Core 3.1. I took a peek at the examples provided by Microsoft. Turns out the Docker file resided in a different place in the solution and Docker copy command wasn't working properly.

You have to move your docker file one directory up, so that they are at the same level as the `sln` file. It will fix the issue.

***OR else you can change the paths like below sample docker file WITHOUT changing the docker file location, IMHO it is better to keep the docker file with other files.***

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim-arm64v8 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WhatzThat.Web.csproj", "WhatzThat.Web/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WhatzThat.Web/WhatzThat.Web.csproj" -r linux-arm64

WORKDIR "/src/WhatzThat.Web"
COPY . .

RUN dotnet build "WhatzThat.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WhatzThat.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish -r linux-arm64 --self-contained false --no-restore

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WhatzThat.Web.dll"]
```

Comment: I struggled with this, and in my case I had already made most of the adjustments to the path as correctly advised in the answer. It turns out the one thing that was breaking my build step was that I had the COPY . . command *before* the WORKDIR command after the restore. Once I corrected this, my build step worked. Thanks for your help, hopefully my additional pointer helps someone as well.

Comment: Can't tell what the changes to the path are. Mind elaborating a bit?

Comment: why would Microsoft do such silly things! Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @CoderSivu That fixed it for me, too. Imagine me thinking I could trust Microsoft to provide correct auto-generated template Dockerfiles from VS2022...

Comment: Along with shaving off the project folder path on the first "copy", indeed moving the "workdir" command ahead of the "copy . ." is a key part of the solution here.

The problem with the original is, I think it really *was* written to run from the solution folder, and the "COPY . ." copies over *all* project folders to src/ (pointlessly - it seems like a mistake that fixed another mistake). I could only get it to run as written using "docker build -t myImage -f myProject\Dockerfile ."

Comment: @CoderSivu wow that fixed it for me too! MS hosed the dockerfile it told us to use!

Comment: Thanks for the tip "move the dockerfile one directory up"
i tried and it worked, so i searched how to avoid moving the file and found you can specify the dockerfile with -f
now i run the docker command from solution folder with -f like the following :
docker build -f myApp\dockerfile .

Comment: thanks @dale  for saving my day. I just put dockerfile out of project directory to the solution path and it worked.

Answer (score 50):

### 2023 Update

Unfortunately, there is an inconsistency in what Microsoft includes in Dockerfile and in which directory you run it.

There are three solutions to get this work.

### First Solution

1. Put your auto-generated Dockerfile one level up, alongside the .sln file.
2. From the root directory of the solution, run the below command

   docker build -t imagename .

---

### Second Solution

1. Leave the Dockerfile as it is, inside your project folder.
2. From the root directory of the solution, run the below command

   docker build -t imagename -f .\SampleProject\Dockerfile .

---

### Third Solution

Make small changes to the Dockerfile. Now you have to run docker commands not from the root directory of the solution, but from your project folder. (one level down from .sln file).

Change from below
[image]

to
[image]

Supplementary

[image]

Comment: Third solutions is excellent example ! Works for me, thanks

Comment: @RamilAliyev Don't you consider voting up if it worked for you?

Comment: Thanks. I figured out Third solution myself, except I missed the last part where you swap the WORKDIR and COPY commands. Not sure why that is needed but w/e at this point

Comment: Thanks! can someone explain about the COPY and WORKDIR. i figured out the rest, but not this

Answer (score 21):

I had the same issue.
I've realized that I had my Docker file at the same level of my .csproj file. I've moved my Docker file one level up in my folder structure and it's building fine.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! But then VS can't build and debug project.

Comment: Oh my god, i had the same issue, just wasted half a day trying to debug. Thanks !

Answer (score 15):

Using a multi-project solution structure, I fixed by adding "src" again into the directory to build.

**Something like this:**

```
COPY ["src/Todo.Core/Todo.Core.csproj", "Todo.Core/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Todo.Api/Todo.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Todo.Api/"
RUN dotnet build "Todo.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
```

**Turned into this:**

```
COPY ["src/Todo.Core/Todo.Core.csproj", "Todo.Core/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Todo.Api/Todo.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/Todo.Api/"
RUN dotnet build "Todo.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
```

Comment: that did the trick for me, thank you!!!!

Comment: You are a life saver, this answer should be higher up! Thank you!

Comment: That dark sorcery worked! I didn't understand why it happened though. I have a WORKDIR at the beginning setted to /src and I copy from my local src/project to project.

Comment: Can't belive I lost hours on this

Answer (score 13):

Compiling and publishing an application inside docker will need entire application to be copied inside docker.
which means you need to copy all class files(.cs) along with required supporting files(maybe resx or config files) inside docker.

please find below reference for same

https://github.com/aspnet/aspnet-docker/issues/401

Comment: mmm isn't this line copying the entire folder to docker? COPY Services/AadTracking ./   In the lines below i also copy the csproj files

Comment: Yes it will copy all the files from Services/AadTracking to ./ however as you are explicitly copying csproj and changing its original location to inside AadTracking folder it looses references to .cs files.
Try doing same thing on local ...copy files as you have mentioned in commands .. and then try using dotnet build command ..issue will reproduce.

Answer (score 4):

For me the COPY.. was after the workdir before the dotnet build command. I just put it after the workdir command. Then it was working.

```
WORKDIR "/src/WeatherAPI"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "WeatherAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
```

Answer (score 3):

My *DockerFile* is at root level not upper and I changed the *DockerFile* to:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

#Depending on the operating system of the host machines(s) that will build or run the containers, the image specified in the FROM statement may need to be changed.
#For more information, please see https://aka.ms/containercompat

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["projectName.csproj", "projectName/"]
RUN dotnet restore "projectName/projectName.csproj"

WORKDIR "/src/projectName"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "projectName.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "projectName.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "projectName.dll"]
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a faux pas reason.

My docker file.......I was correctly copying the **directory structure** and the .sln and .csproj files...........

But I had a syntax error copying the SOURCE files. (.cs files, etc, etc)

#doh!

If you look at the question above, basically I had a syntax-error/bug in the steps right below where the OP has this:

```
# COPY source code
```

More importantly, how did I figure this out ???  Here ya go:

```
docker images
```

and you do not want to drill into the last one (which is your failing image), but the NEXT TO LAST image.  (remembering that docker keeps making new images for the steps of the docker file)

```
docker images

REPOSITORY           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
mything1/mything2    latest              aaaaaaaaaaaa        27 minutes ago      271MB
<none>               <none>              bbbbbbbbbbbb        27 minutes ago      1.18GB
```

and then drill into (the next to last one)

```
docker run --rm -it bbbbbbbbbbbb  sh
```

when you get in there, start using "ls" and "cd" commands.

I found out I didn't have my .cs source files in the right place.  A few fixes addressing relative-path issues (in my specific case) later......I had my source files in the right place(s).  #yay

This is a great in-general tip for when trying to debug a failing non running image.

Answer (score 2):

Answer by marvelTracker worked for me but busted using the built in Docker tools in Visual Studio 2022.

Using the command `docker build -f Dockerfile ..` while in the project folder builds the dockerfile from the perspective of the parent folder.

Microsoft Doc that explains building Docker in VS2022: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-build?view=vs-2022

NOTE: I found this troubleshooting the same error for a .NET 6 Docker project.

Hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that the file containing the Main method is NOT included so you either forgot to copy it over to the proper directory or docker is point to the incorrect directory.

Answer (score 0):

From the folder having Dockerfile at present,

execute

```
mv Dockerfile ../
```

then invoke

```
docker build
```

Comment: This is essentially a less-detailed duplicate of the already selected answer.

Comment: This doesn't even address the error in the question

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue and manage to identify the root cause.

The issue occurred because I run the application on my windows machine before I build the docker Linux image.

Because I run it on my local windows it generate `obj` folder on the source code, the `obj` folder got copied to Docker container which contain **windows specific assembly** version IMHO.

To fix the issue I simply delete the `obj` folder from my project and rebuild the Docker.

Lesson learned, do build your Docker images on a freshly cloned repository.