# Docker gets error "failed to compute cache key: not found" - runs fine in Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio, docker, command-line-interface, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've generated a Dockerfile with Visual Studio. It runs in Visual Studio just fine and now I'm trying to build it from Windows itself (`docker build .`, and I tried many combinations). Yet I get the following error:

```
> [build 3/7] COPY [client/client.csproj, client/]:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/client/client.csproj" not found: not found
```

When I change copy to `./client.csproj` it does continue and then I get:

```
 => ERROR [build 7/7] RUN dotnet build "client.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build                3.3s
------
> [build 7/7] RUN dotnet build "client.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build:
#15 0.652 Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.8.3+39993d9d for .NET
#15 0.652 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
#15 0.652
#15 1.169   Determining projects to restore...
#15 1.483   All projects are up-to-date for restore.
#15 3.231 CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [/src/client/client.csproj]
#15 3.240
#15 3.240 Build FAILED.
#15 3.240
#15 3.240 CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [/src/client/client.csproj]
#15 3.240     0 Warning (5)
#15 3.240     1 Error (5)
#15 3.240
#15 3.240 Time Elapsed 00:00:02.51
-----
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dotnet build "client.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build]: exit code: 1
```

What am I doing wrong? I changed Docker Linux to Windows, changed [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux), and restarted everything.

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visua...

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["client/client.csproj", "client/"]
RUN dotnet restore "client/client.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/client"
RUN dotnet build "client.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "client.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet', "client.dll"]
```

Comment: It's work for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/63257667/15203500
You have to move your docker file One directory up

Answer (score 242, accepted):

The way Visual Studio does it is a little bit odd.

Instead of launching `docker build` in the folder with the Dockerfile, it launches in the parent folder and specifies the Dockerfile with the `-f` option.

I was using the demo project (trying to create a minimal solution for another question) and struck the same situation.

Setup for my demo project is

```
\WorkerService2  ("solution" folder)
   +- WorkerService2.sln
   +- WorkserService2  ("project" folder)
       +- DockerFile
       +- WorkerService2.csproj
       +- ... other program files
```

So I would **expect** to go

```
cd \Workerservice2\WorkerService2
docker build .
```

But I get your error message.

```
 => ERROR [build 3/7] COPY [WorkerService2/WorkerService2.csproj, WorkerService2/]                                                                                                                        0.0s
------
 > [build 3/7] COPY [WorkerService2/WorkerService2.csproj, WorkerService2/]:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/WorkerService2/WorkerService2.csproj" not found: not found
```

Instead, go to the parent directory, with the `.sln` file and use the docker `-f` option to specify the Dockerfile to use in the subfolder:

```
cd \Workerservice2
docker build -f WorkerService2\Dockerfile --force-rm -t worker2/try7 .

docker run -it worker2/try7
```

---

Note the final dot on the `docker build` command.

For docker the final part of the command is the location of the files that Docker will work with. *Usually* this is the folder with the Dockerfile in, but that's what's different about how VS does it. In this case the dockerfile is specified with the `-f`. Any paths (such as with the `COPY` instruction in the dockerfile) are relative to the location specified. The `.` means "current directory", which in my example is `\WorkerService2`.

I got to this stage by inspecting the output of the build process, with verbosity set to Detailed.
If you choose Tools / Options / Projects and Solutions / Build and Run you can adjust the build output verbosity, I made mine Detailed.

---

I think I've worked out why Visual Studio does it this way.
It allows the project references in the same solution to be copied in.

If it was set up to do `docker build` from the project folder, docker would not be able to `COPY` any of the other projects in the solution in. But the way this is set up, with current directory being the solution folder, you can copy referenced projects (subfolders) into your docker build process.

Comment: Gah.  It was that last dot that was getting me.  I tried all sorts of combinations of the full file or a path without the file, but I either got the `file not found` issue, or the dreaded `docker build requires exactly 1 argument` message.  Not gonna lie, learning the tiniest new thing in docker is like pulling teeth, FFS.  It works great once you figure out the obscure syntax and methods, but until then it's one headdesk after another.

Comment: Yeah, what's the dot at the end for?  You're specifying two docker files.

Comment: @tblev The '.' at the end is telling docker which directory to run from, in this case, the root of the solution rather than the project. Careful though, the COPY command is case sensitive and if you have your project directory named inconsistently with the command (camel case etc.) that will confuse docker

Comment: i had this problem, just check your path for typo

Comment: I think this answer helps a lot. I had a similar problem when working with devcontainers in vscode. When inspecting the `docker buildx build` command when opening a folder in a container I saw that the command does not end with a `.` but with `/path/to/repo/workingdir`. The `Dockerfile` resided in `workingdir/subdir/.devcontainter`. So instead of `COPY file.txt .` I had to use `COPY subdir/file.txt`.

Comment: I love the inclusion of the debugging process in a small note after the answer itself! Noting how to get detailed verbosity with the IDE at hand is very useful to independent visitors.

Comment: Wow spent too much time searching for a solution. Many thanks

Comment: Better to use `docker build -f Dockerfile ..` from the directory where the Dockerfile exists (Note the 2 dots at the end). Official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-build?view=vs-2022#use-docker-build.

Answer (score 443):

Check your `.dockerignore` file. Possible it ignores needed files for copy command and you get failed to compute cache key error.

`.dockerignore` may be configured to minimize the files sent to docker for performance and security:

```
* 
!dist/
```

The first line `*` disallows all files.  The second line `!dist/` allows the `dist` folder

This can cause unexpected behavior:

```
FROM nginx:latest

# Fails because of * in .dockerignore
# failed to compute cache key: "/nginx.conf.spa" not found: not found
# Fix by adding `!nginx.conf.spa`  to .dockerignore
COPY nginx.conf.spa /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

RUN mkdir /app

# Works because of !dist/ in .dockerignore
COPY dist/spa /app
```

Belts and suspenders.

Answer (score 30):

I had the same issue, I set the Docker environment to Windows in when adding Docker support. Even running in Visual Studio threw error to that. I changed the environment to Linux as my Docker is running in the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).

Then I moved back to the terminal to run the commands.

I was able to resolve this by moving to the Solutions folder (Root folder).

And I did `docker build` like this:

```
docker build -t containername/tag -f ProjectFolder/Dockerfile .
```

Then I did `docker run`:

```
docker run containername/tag
```

Comment: Using -f option in the .sln-folder had already been an answer 10 days before this answer.

Comment: Re *"Linux Subsystem for Windows"*: Do you mean *[Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)* (WSL)?

Answer (score 21):

Asking for a directory that does not exist throws this error.

In my case, I tried

```
 > [stage-1  7/14] COPY /.ssh/id_rsa.pub /.ssh/:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" not found: not found
```

I had forgotten to add the `/.ssh` folder to the project directory. In your case you should check whether `/client` is really a subfolder of your Dockerfile build context.

Comment: same here, made a typo

Comment: Or maybe you renamed/moved a file that used to be referenced in your Docker file (ADD/COPY/etc.) and now is missing for the docker build to run. Whatever makes it be missing.

Comment: Same in my case. Glad I searched this. I simply didn't think to check for a typo, lol

Answer (score 18):

The following command was failing with `failed to compute cache key: not found`:

```
docker build -t tag-name:v1.5.1 - <Dockerfile
```

Upon changing the command to the following it got fixed:

```
docker build -t tag-name:v1.5.1 -f Dockerfile .
```

Comment: Simply doing `docker build .` worked for me since "_Dockerfile_" is the default dockerfile filename.

Answer (score 7):

In my case I found that docker build is case sensitive in directory name, so I was writing /bin/release/net5.0/publish in the COPY instruction and failed with the same error, I've just changed to /bin/Release/net5.0/publish and it worked

Comment: This was the answer for me.  Windows not being case sensitive on pathing makes working with docker fun sometimes.

Answer (score 7):

```
Error : failed to compute cache key: "src" not found: not found
```

in my case , `folder/file` excluded in `.dockerignore`

after resolving file from dockerignore able to create image.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I had something like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
COPY bin/Release/net5.0/publish/ app/
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApi.dll"]
```

And I finally realized that I had the **bin** folder in my .dockerignore file.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issues: Apparently, `docker` roots the file system during build to the specified build directory for security reasons. As a result, `COPY` and `ADD` cannot refer to arbitrary locations on the host file system. Additionally, there are other issues with syntax peculiarities. What eventually worked was the following:

```
COPY ./script_file.sh  /
RUN /script_file.sh
```

Comment: Other solutions here were overkill.  This was simplest and cleanest. However, you may need to run `docker builder prune`  if you still get cache errors.

Comment: Yup this is what fixed it for me, was specifying an absolute path

Answer (score 4):

It's all due to an error in the dockerignore file.
If you check that the file has ignore target then leave it out

Answer (score 2):

In my case I changed context, and path of Dockerfile within docker-compose.yml config:

```
services:
    server:
        # inheritance structru
        extends:
            file: ../../docker-compose.server.yml
        # I recommend you to play with this paths
        build:
            context: ../../
            dockerfile: ./apps/${APP_NAME}/Dockerfile
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. In my case there was a wrong directory specified.
My Dockerfile was:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS publish
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o publish/web src/MyApp/MyApp.csproj

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish publish/web .
EXPOSE 80
CMD ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:$PORT dotnet MyApp.dll
```

Then I realised that in the second build stage I am trying to copy project files from directory `publish/web`:

```
COPY --from=publish publish/web .
```

But as I specified workdir /app in the first stage, my files are located in that directory in image filesystem, so changing path from `publish/web` to `app/publish/web` resolved my issue.

So my final working Dockerfile is:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS publish
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o publish/web src/MyApp/MyApp.csproj

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish app/publish/web .
EXPOSE 80
CMD ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:$PORT dotnet MyApp.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was a sneaky trailing whitespace in the file name.

```
------
 > [3/3] COPY init.sh ./:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/init.sh" not found: not found
```

So the file was actually called "init.sh " instead of "init.sh".

Answer (score 1):

The nginx.conf file must be included to be published. Right Click on the nginx.conf file and open the Properties. Change "Copy to output directory" to "Copy always"

Answer (score 1):

Use `docker build -f Dockerfile ..` from the directory where the Dockerfile exists (Note the 2 dots at the end). Official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-build?view=vs-2022#use-docker-build

Answer (score 1):

Moving the Dockerfile one folder up as suggested by m.mitin worked for me as well. The instructions in the Dockerfile assume it is outside the project folder, it has nothing to do with minimization of files. In fact, I deliberately copied the project files directly onto my server and got the same error. I think the team at Microsoft should do something about to avoid productivity loss caused by this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue.

The reason was the name of the DLL file in the Docker file is case sensitive.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY MyFirstMicroService.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c release -o /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "**MyFirstMicroService.dll**"]
```

This *.dll* name should match your .csproj file.

Answer (score 0):

This also happens when you don't provide the proper path to your COPY command input. The most important clue I had is that WORKDIR command opens a folder for the container, not in the windows explorer (so it doesn't affect the path you need to specify for the COPY command).

Answer (score 0):

In my Case,
i was doing mistake in '/' and ''. Let me explain
Open your dockerfile (it should be named as dockerfile only, not DockerFile or Dockerfile).
You may have something like this-
*FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0
**COPY bin\Release\net5.0\publish .**
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "HelloDocker.dll"]*

Replace **COPY bin\Release\net5.0\publish .** to **COPY bin/Release/net5.0/publish .**

Answer (score 0):

in my case, it was a wrong [Build with PATH](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#build-with-path) configuration e.g. Docker `build context`

1. Simple docker script

   ```sh
   docker build .
   ```

   where `.` is path to build context
2. [Gradle+Docker](https://github.com/palantir/gradle-docker)

   ```
   docker {
       dependsOn build
       dependsOn dockerFilesCopy
       name "${project.name}:${project.version}"
       files "build" // path to build context
   }
   ```
3. [Gradle+GitHub action](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action)

   ```yaml
   name: Docker build and push

   on:
     push:
       branches: [ main ]

   # ...

   jobs:
     build:
       runs-on: ubuntu-latest

       # ...

       steps:
         - name: Checkout
           uses: actions/checkout@v2

        # ...

         - name: Build and export to Docker
           uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
           with:
             # ...
             file: src/main/docker/Dockerfile      
             context: ./build                      # path to build context
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, with Angular project, my project was in the folder called ex: My-Folder-Project and I was putting on Dockerfile COPY --from=publish app/dist/My-Folder-Project .
But of course the correct thing is put the "name" in your package.json like COPY --from=publish app/dist/name-in-package.json .

Answer (score 0):

I run into a similar issue where I was attempting to run the docker build command. I created a folder called "Docker" and inside of it another folder called "getting-started". I kept running into the error:

"*failed to compute cache key: "/public" not found: not found*"

Took me a while to realize that I should run the command from the "getting-started" folder instead of "Docker". It worked on I did so..

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel users...

I got this error when running `docker compose up` and it was due to there being a storage folder symlink in my public folder.

After deleting the symlink, the command executed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error, first it resolved by removing some files from .dockerignore.

After that, I used a variable and haven't used $ operator to resolve it.
Added $ before "{variable}", it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone coming here after googling struggling with this on an ARM based Mac, you can try disabling Rosetta emulation in docker desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, my dockerfile looked like this:

```
FROM node:18

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ /app
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm run dev
```

then it gave me the error: `npm cound not find package.json`

and after adding this to dockerfile:

```
COPY ./package.json ./app
```

and running the command :

`docker build -f Dockerfile .` (don't forget to add the dot at the end)

and that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the copy command was using parent directories:

```
COPY ../../../www /var/www/
```

I had to change to

```
COPY ./www /var/www/
```

and it worked for me