# How to COPY files from within WSL to a Docker container

Tags: docker, path, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Docker installed and running in Windows but using WSL 2 based engine. I have some files that are in WSL 2 and that I wand to copy into the image during the build.

```
COPY MY_FILES_IN_WSL /home/lector/
```

I could not figure out how to create the path to those files (it is `/home/niels/Tei-xslt` with WSL) since, obviously \wsl$ is not working in the Dockerfile but using the linux path as well does not work.

I always get a similar error message like this one:

```
failed to compute cache key: "/Tei-xslt" not found: not found
The terminal process "C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe -e docker build --pull --rm -f "Dockerfile" -t melusina:latest "."" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

I also tried relative and absolute paths.

Is there a possibility to refer to those files?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67944726/2777988

Comment: thx. for the response but the referenced ticket is not our problem - at least something that should not work with this explanation works and the other way around