# GCP Dataflow Go Flex Template - COPY wordcount: failed to compute cache key: "/wordcount" not found: not found

Tags: docker, go, google-cloud-dataflow

I've been building python flex templates and would like to test out one in go. Following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-go-flex-templates) I ran into an error running `docker build .`

My guess is that there is something simple I'm missing to do with setting up a go package

*image*

```
FROM gcr.io/dataflow-templates-base/go-template-launcher-base

ARG WORKDIR=/dataflow/template
RUN mkdir -p ${WORKDIR}

COPY wordcount ${WORKDIR}/wordcount

ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_GO_BINARY="${WORKDIR}/wordcount"

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/google/dataflow/go_template_launcher"]
```

*error*

```
 => ERROR [3/3] COPY wordcount /dataflow/template/wordcount                                                            0.0s
------
 > [3/3] COPY wordcount /dataflow/template/wordcount:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/wordcount" not found: not found
```

*tree*

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
├── metadata.json
├── wordcount.go
└── wordcount_test.go
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker - failed to compute cache key: not found - runs fine in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66146088/docker-failed-to-compute-cache-key-not-found-runs-fine-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Did you tried running ```gcloud auth configure-docker REGION-docker.pkg.dev```  mentioned in the tutorial ?

Comment: Seems like you need to compile your `wordcount.go` first?