# docker - weird copy --from behaviour while multistaging

Tags: docker, vite, react-typescript, docker-multi-stage-build

I'm trying to set up dev, preview-staging and prod images of Vite+ReactTS via single Dockerfile using [multistaging](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/)

Here's Dockerfile's content:

```
#
# ---- Base Image ----
# Use to set up defaults
#
ARG APP_DIR_PATH=app
ARG BASE_IMAGE_VER=20.5.1-alpine3.18
ARG BUILD_PLATFORM=linux/amd64
FROM --platform=${BUILD_PLATFORM} node:${BASE_IMAGE_VER} AS base

# see https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/main/docs/BestPractices.md
RUN apk add --no-cache tini
ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "--"]

WORKDIR /${APP_DIR_PATH}

ENV NODE_PM=pnpm
RUN npm i -g ${NODE_PM}

COPY package.json ./
COPY pnpm-lock.yaml ./

#
# ---- Dependencies Image ----
# Use to hold cached node_modules ?and prod_modules separate?
#
ARG DEV_NODE_MODULES_DIR_PATH=node_modules
ARG PROD_NODE_MODULES_DIR_PATH=prod_${DEV_NODE_MODULES_DIR_PATH}
FROM base AS dependencies
RUN ${NODE_PM} i -P

# Possibly we don't need prod copy of packages due to Vite uses tsc and itself for build and preview
# for now they are in devDependencies, so...
RUN cp -R ./${DEV_NODE_MODULES_DIR_PATH} ./${PROD_NODE_MODULES_DIR_PATH}

RUN ${NODE_PM} i

#
# ---- Development Image ----
# Use in development
# Note: rebuild image after every package.json|.configs changing
#
ARG VITE_PORT=8080
FROM dependencies AS dev
COPY ./ ./

# keep tracking ./src/
RUN --mount=type=bind,target=./src/,source=./src/,rw=false

ENV VITE_PORT=${VITE_PORT}
EXPOSE ${VITE_PORT}

CMD ["pnpm", "dev"]

#
# ---- Build Image ----
# Use for production's preview
# Note: rebuild image after every package.json|.configs changing
#
ARG BUILD_DIR_PATH=dist
FROM dev AS build

ENV NODE_ENV=production

COPY ./ ./
RUN ${NODE_PM} build --outDir ./${BUILD_DIR_PATH}

CMD ["pnpm", "preview", "--port", "${VITE_PORT}"]

#
# ---- Production Image ----
# Use in production
# Note: rebuild image after every new change
#
# ARG BASE_PROD_IMAGE_VER=1.25.2-alpine
FROM --platform=${BUILD_PLATFORM} nginx:1.25.2-alpine AS prod
WORKDIR /

COPY ./.configs/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html/

EXPOSE 80 443

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Always getting error at `prod` image staging at line

```
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

With this output

```
 => ERROR [prod 4/5] COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html/                                                                      0.0s 
------
 > [prod 4/5] COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html/:
------
build.Dockerfile:85
--------------------
  83 |     RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
  84 |
  85 | >>> COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html/
  86 |
  87 |     EXPOSE 80 443
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 122aaccf-8f31-4e47-aff8-56e3d80edefb::zni94o6alhuq2gp7tryq3q8t0: failed to walk /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount959429879/app: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount959429879/app: no such file or directory
```

I don't have any idea what is going on in stderr

I'm using Docker(v24.0.5) on Windows

## What I've tried

Nothing at all over stackoverflow

Comment: Q: Based on what you found (with /usr/share/nginx and caching), is there anything you can do by adding entries to your .dockerignore file?  NOTE: In case others come across this post: Look at the various responses here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66146088/421195

Answer (score 1):

There is a specific bug in the way you're using build-time `ARG`.

Each `FROM` line starts a new image and resets the build environment.  In particular that resets the sets of `ARG` that are "in scope".  You can [put `ARG` before `FROM`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact) but the only things you can do with these `ARG`s are set default values and use them in `FROM` lines.

Your Dockerfile approximately starts with (in this order)

```bash
ARG APP_DIR_PATH=app
FROM node AS base
WORKDIR /${APP_DIR_PATH}
```

Since you don't repeat the `ARG` after the `FROM` line, it's not set in the `base` build stage.  That means the `$APP_DIR_PATH` variable is empty at this point in the setup.  That's not an error, you just execute `WORKDIR /` and carry on from here.  When you get to the `build` stage, you build into `/dist` and not `/app/dist` and that results in the problem you eventually see.

This error seems to be repeated for every build stage; you have `ARG` declared immediately *before* the `FROM` line starting the stage that uses it.  I suspect you're avoiding trouble here only because this Dockerfile is so linear, every stage inherits from its immediate predecessor.  If you had a separate path `FROM base` that installed only production modules it might see similar issues around undefined variables.

You have a lot of variables for things like filesystem paths and command names that don't quite make sense here.  This is doubly true for things like the `node_modules` directory that have fixed names.  (Ask, would you *ever* change these things?  Platform or Node version, yes; changing `pnpm` to `yarn`, not without some other rearrangement.)  I'd remove many of these variables, which avoids some ambiguity

```bash
WORKDIR /app       # fixed filesystem layout inside the image
RUN npm i -g pnpm  # fixed npm package name of alternate package manager
RUN pnpm i -P      # different package managers will have different options
EXPOSE 8080        # matches listen() call in code
```

Answer (score 0):

Weird output: It was caching issue

Problem solve: change

```
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

to

```
COPY --from=build /dist /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

reason: `WORKDIR` of base stage-image, in this case `build` image

Comment: It's not weird that's how you have defined the WORKDIR in your Build staging