# Docker for ASP.NET Core 6 Web API

Tags: docker, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have a problem and I want to create a docker for an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, the library does not have a main function so it still has an error when running the build:

> #20 6.813 CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [/src/src/api/Jalasoft.Dev33Level2.Programs.Api/Jalasoft.Dev33Level2.Programs.Api.csproj]

The `program.cs` is different because I use the .NET 6 SDK, as I knew it before so if it does not have a main function:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Now the docker I use is the following, I use this and the .NET 6 SDK is what causes the error possibly:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000

# https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY Programs/*.sln ./
COPY Programs/src/api/Programs.Api/*.csproj ./src/api/Programs.Api/
COPY Programs/src/core/Programs.Service/*.csproj ./src/core/Programs.Service/
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /src/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /src/publish --no-restore

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /src/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Jalasoft.Dev33Level2.Programs.Api.dll"]
```

Comment: [Does this answer useful to you ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69928436/docker-net-6-error-program-does-not-contain-a-static-main-method-suitable-for)

Comment: are you with the Implicit global usings enabled on the main project?