# Can't publish WPF Application even if I can build in VS2019

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have an WPF Solution with 1 project inside, everything works fine in debug & release mode inside VS2019.
But I can't run `dotnet publish` inside the project,

I have the following errors :

```
error CS1558: 'App' does not have a suitable static 'Main' method [C:\Users\Alpha\Alpha\Alpha.csproj]
C:\Users\Alpha\Alpha\Dialogs\Views\DialogAddTestView.xaml.cs(25,13): error CS0103: The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context [C:\Users\Alpha\Alpha\Alpha.csproj]
```

*and many more InitializeComponent errors*

I really can't figure out why,

I checked the project configuration and made sure that the build action of App.xaml is ApplicationDefinition.

(I have tried all the solutions found here [Does not contain a static 'main' method suitable for an entry point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607702/does-not-contain-a-static-main-method-suitable-for-an-entry-point))

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. VS2019, I build for .Net Framework 4.8. 

WPF User Control Library is my project (there is no App.xml). It is referenced by another project which is a Windows Executable. The whole thing works in the IDE, but `dotnet publish` gives your 'InitializeComponent' error. 

Are these your settings ?

Comment: I am still stuck with this error... But I have only a single app inside my project, building for .NET 4.7.2 with my app selected as the startup app.

Comment: Is your WPF application a .NET Framework or .NET Core application? If it is .NET Framework application then you should use corresponding msbuild to publish it.