# "does not contain a static 'Main' method" error

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I'm getting the below error at the time I run the Windows application on my program. Can any one help?

> Error:     Program 'C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\Project1\Integer Division\Integer
>   Division\obj\Debug\Integer Division.exe' does not contain a static
>   'Main' method suitable for an entry point Integer Division

Comment: Isn't it self explainatory.?

Comment: self explainatory, you are missing a Main method which acts as an entry point for .net applications

Comment: Not self explaining when there's already a static Main method in the application. This is a real problem because one has no clue where to go.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a:

```
static void Main()
{
}
```

If you want to "run" something a main is needed. That is basically the main function as the name implies where your program will run. You should look up any class example with a main() inside of it and put your code inside (the one for integral division ?).

Answer (score 0):

[Does not contain a static 'main' method suitable for an entry point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607702/does-not-contain-a-static-main-method-suitable-for-an-entry-point)

or

[Troubleshooting "program does not contain a static 'Main' method" when it clearly does...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386831/troubleshooting-program-does-not-contain-a-static-main-method-when-it-clearl)

But it's not related to Integer Division, for sure.

Comment: integer division must be his project name

Comment: I think I have the Main method in the program. However I still getting same error. here is the code, please help............

Comment: public class frmMain : Form
{
    private Label label1;
    private Label label2;
    private TextBox txtOperand2;
    private TextBox txtResult;
    private Button btnResult;
    private Button btnExit;
    private TextBox txtOperand1;

    #region Window code
    private void initializeComponent()
    {
    }
    #endregion

    public frmMain()
    {
        initializeComponent();
    }

    public static void main()
    {
        frmMain main = new frmMain();
        Application.Run(main);
    }

Comment: @YoselinMedina from what you posted it is WinForms application...  Try to create new WinForm project and analyze it - your project should have same default classes and same default methods. Be carefull - they **must not** be overriden