# [A]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection cannot be cast to... web.config issue

Tags: c#, web-config, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I am getting the following error:

> [A]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection cannot be cast
>   to [B]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection. Type A
>   originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context
>   'Default' at location
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'.
>   Type B originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context
>   'Default' at location 'C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\63e7ff36\a1cb775d\assembly\dl3\8f568c18\9b7ddacf_d04dcf01\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'.

I have searched across stackoverflow for similar issues and I used their solutions but it doesn't seem to fix the issue I am experiencing.

It suddenly occurred, I just pressed clean solution and this error popped up. I also started using nuget package restore on the solution. I updated my packages as well (using Update-package) so one of those might have something to do with this issue.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The cause of this error is the web.config in the Views folder referencing System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0 instead of 3.0.0.0.

Typically this can happen after a nuget-package upgrade, which does not account for this folder.

Update the `Views\Web.config` file:

```
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
```

for more information on upgrading to MVC 5 http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2

Comment: it doesn't sound like a fix rather work around to me. some projects might be depending on mvc4 only

Comment: In particular, it looks like the fix for this error isin the "Update the web.config files under the Views folder" section. It seems updating from MVC4 -> MVC5 with NuGet doesn't automatically update the version numbers in Views/Web.config.

Comment: Thanks for the link! It would have been nice if the NuGet update could have at least shown a link to that page...

Comment: I followed the guide and now I can't run my site in debug mode - tells me "... Project with output type of Class Library cannot be started..."

Comment: Follow-up:  if you go to this other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456648/how-can-i-get-my-web-api-app-to-run-again-after-upgrading-to-mvc-5-and-web-api-2) you will see the second answer helped me after this broke down.

Comment: Worked for me, my primary issue was caused because I hadn't updated the versions in the web.config in the Views sub-folder.

Answer (score 283):

I am using VS2013, MVC 5.2.2.0, Web Api 2. I have just changed the all versions from **2.0.0.0** to **3.0.0.0** of the following section of **Web.config** resides inside the **View** folder of my project.

```
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
```

And the problem gets solved.
BINGO !!

Comment: This solved it for me. I'm converting a webforms app to MVC5.

Comment: @guneysus, how would you do the equivalent of Kuntal's answer without manual editing?

Comment: @twm Generally `Update-Package` edits also `web.config`

Comment: This almost solved my problem and pointed me in the right direction. The configSection in my views web.config was alreasy at version 3.0.0.0. But theres also an assemblyBinding section in the root web.config that needed to be upgraded from 2.0.0.0 to 3.0.0.0. Look for dependentAssembly System.Web.WebPages.Razor. Thanks

Comment: Also check main web.config for <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />. Bumping that to 3.0.0.0 was the last fix for me.

Comment: This worked for me, however I still can't call this using AJAX... any idea? It works if I debug the Web API from VS. If I create another project and call it through JQuery Ajax, I get an error. Any idea? 
UPDATE: I realized the `origins` in the header specifies which website will access it and once I fixed that, it worked fine. Thanks for the help. +1

Comment: This worked for me. Visual Studio 2019, Targeting .NET 4.6.1, MVC 5.2.7. Thanks! (before this, I had to change app key "webpages:Version" to 3.0.0.0, which is why I also had to change sectiongroup - noted above)

Answer (score 105):

Just adding my two cents to this issue.

I found that the cause of this error for me was that the **Views folders** web.config was referencing   `System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0` when everything else was using `3.0.0.0`

Seems the nuget-package upgrade didn't account for this folder somehow.

Comment: its more precise! web.config in views folder.

Answer (score 14):

Tried all the methods above, and the issue was still not solved until I inserted the following lines in web.config directly under project folder.

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you get this with the Route Debugger then you need to update the web.config in the Views folder under the Area for the Route Debugger.

Comment: Lifesaver. Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify that please.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I've solved this by also updating the **Web.config** on the live server which the VS has updated upon upgrading to MVC 5