# cs5001 error program `a.out' does not contain a static `main' method suitable for an entry point

Tags: c#, static, program-entry-point, void, public

```
using System;

namespace Функции
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Print ("Hi!");
            int kys;
                kys = cry(7, 3);
            Print (kys);
        }

        private static void Print(string v)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        public static void Print(int kys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(kys);
        }

        public static int cry (int a, int b)  
        {
            int rip;
            rip = a + b;

            return rip; 
        }
    }
}
```

I think I added main so I don't know what happened

Comment: did you re-build the executable after adding `Main`?

Comment: no,how can i do it?

Comment: In VisualStudio: Build > Build solution
With .NET Core: `dotnet build`

Comment: If you plan to stick to c# for a while, then start with [naming guideline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines). As for you issue, try giving namespace an non-cyrillic name (e.g. `Functions`). Not sure what `a.out` in errors means, shouldn't it be the path? Have you been [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/386831/1997232) ?